# How do you do relative time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a Rails application, but can't seem to find how to do relative time, i.e. if given a certain Time class, it can calculate "30 seconds ago" or "2 days ago" or if it's longer than a month "9/1/2008", etc.

Comment: 'calculate' seems to be the wrong word, did you mean 'output'?

Answer (score 375):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`time_ago_in_words`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) method (or [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words)), from ActiveSupport. Call it like this:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(timestamp) %>
```

Comment: Hints for a ruby newbie on how to run this in irb?  I run: require 'active_support' and then try 'time_ago_in_words(Time.now)' but the function isn't found.

Comment: @cboettig It's not part of `ActiveSupport`, it's defined in `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`.

Comment: you don't need to require 'active_support' if you are in a rails console. there is a console method called `helper` that you can call and access these methods.

`helper.time_ago_in_words(timestamp)`

Comment: Just fyi, if you want this in irb, or plain Ruby, just do a:

    ```require 'active_support/core_ext'```

First, and then you're all set for using `7.days.ago` and other similar constructs.

Comment: great! i've just came here expecting some sample code and found this.I love ruby and rails

Comment: The "N.units.since" construct still bugs me, I wish they had used "N.units.hence" to denote times in the future...

Comment: This is why I love Ruby

Answer (score 52):

I've written this, but have to check the existing methods mentioned to see if they are better.

```
module PrettyDate
  def to_pretty
    a = (Time.now-self).to_i

    case a
      when 0 then 'just now'
      when 1 then 'a second ago'
      when 2..59 then a.to_s+' seconds ago' 
      when 60..119 then 'a minute ago' #120 = 2 minutes
      when 120..3540 then (a/60).to_i.to_s+' minutes ago'
      when 3541..7100 then 'an hour ago' # 3600 = 1 hour
      when 7101..82800 then ((a+99)/3600).to_i.to_s+' hours ago' 
      when 82801..172000 then 'a day ago' # 86400 = 1 day
      when 172001..518400 then ((a+800)/(60*60*24)).to_i.to_s+' days ago'
      when 518400..1036800 then 'a week ago'
      else ((a+180000)/(60*60*24*7)).to_i.to_s+' weeks ago'
    end
  end
end

Time.send :include, PrettyDate
```

Comment: Hum, I read first ruby, and ruby don't have ActiveSupport out of the box. So I think this post is more ruby.
However in the actual question there is a mention of rails.

Comment: Rails is a web framework and the underlying language is ruby. So it is normal to get some ruby code on a rails question. Even if standard ruby does not include ActiveRecord, it is supported with just a "gem install activerecord" command.

Comment: You can put the last `return`-line within the `case` statement under `else`, and remove all of the `return`s.

Comment: can someone tell why there is `+99` `+800` `+180000` ?

Comment: +99 because the end of "an hour ago" ends at 7100, which is 100 seconds short of two hours. Similarly, +800, since 172000 is 800 seconds short of two days (172800 seconds), and so forth.

Comment: a nice example of how even a single use value can benefit from being a named variable

Answer (score 25):

Just to clarify Andrew Marshall's solution for using **time_ago_in_words**

(For Rails 3.0 and Rails 4.0)

If you are in a view

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(Date.today - 1) %>
```

If you are in a controller

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
def index
  @sexy_date = time_ago_in_words(Date.today - 1)
end
```

Controllers do not have the module [**ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) imported by default.

N.B. It is not "the rails way" to import helpers into your controllers.  Helpers are for helping views.  The **time_ago_in_words** method was decided to be a **view** entity in the **MVC** triad.  (I don't agree but when in rome...)

Answer (score 20):

What about

```
30.seconds.ago
2.days.ago
```

Or something else you were shooting for?

Comment: this is backwards from what the question is stating.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the arithmetic operators to do relative time.

```
Time.now - 2.days
```

Will give you 2 days ago.

Comment: Did you know about 2.days.ago ?

Comment: is there shorthand method for `Time.now + 2.days' ?

Comment: @NixNinja: `2.days.since` or `2.days.from_now`

Comment: this is backwards from what the question was asking.  time_ago_in_words is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this would work.

```
def relative_time(start_time)
  diff_seconds = Time.now - start_time
  case diff_seconds
    when 0 .. 59
      puts "#{diff_seconds} seconds ago"
    when 60 .. (3600-1)
      puts "#{diff_seconds/60} minutes ago"
    when 3600 .. (3600*24-1)
      puts "#{diff_seconds/3600} hours ago"
    when (3600*24) .. (3600*24*30) 
      puts "#{diff_seconds/(3600*24)} days ago"
    else
      puts start_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end
```

Comment: This is essentially a reimplementation of the distance_of_time_in_words helper: http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001712

Comment: which means you shouldn't use it and you should use the built-in

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me. It allows you to customize the rest of the strings. i.e. "3 seconds ago" vs "3s ago"

Comment: `#{diff_seconds/360}` should be `#{diff_seconds/3600}`. I've edited it.

Answer (score 7):

Since the most answer here suggests **time_ago_in_words**.

Instead of using :

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
```

In Rails, prefer:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="<%= comment.created_at.getutc.iso8601 %>">
  <%= comment.created_at.to_s %>
</abbr>
```

along with a jQuery library http://timeago.yarp.com/, with code:

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();
```

Main advantage: caching

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2012/02/10/not-use-time_ago_in_words/

Comment: actually, it is `time_ago_in_words` not time**S**

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the instance methods here:

http://apidock.com/rails/Time

This has useful methods such as yesterday, tomorrow, beginning_of_week, ago, etc.

Examples:

```
Time.now.yesterday
Time.now.ago(2.days).end_of_day
Time.now.next_month.beginning_of_month
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're building a Rails application, you should use

```
Time.zone.now
Time.zone.today
Time.zone.yesterday
```

This gives you time or date in the timezone with which you've configured your Rails application.

For example, if you configure your application to use UTC, then `Time.zone.now` will always be in UTC time (it won't be impacted by the change of British Summertime for example).

Calculating relative time is easy, eg

```
Time.zone.now - 10.minute
Time.zone.today.days_ago(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a gem that does this for Rails ActiveRecord objects. The example uses created_at, but it will also work on updated_at or anything with the class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

Just gem install and call the 'pretty' method on your TimeWithZone instance.

https://github.com/brettshollenberger/hublot

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to unload some logic from the backend and maek the browser do the job by using Javascript plugins such as:

[jQuery time ago](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago) or its [Rails Gem adaptation](https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago)