# Format date/time in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I received a date and time in this format

```
2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530
```

I am wondering how can show it this way `XYZ hours ago` in ruby.

Thanks

UPDATE: I tried `time_ago_in_words' and it gives me the error`undefined method `time_ago_in_words'`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195740/how-do-you-do-relative-time-in-rails

Comment: try this time_ago_in_words(Time.now)

Comment: Is this plain ruby or is it inside a rails view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a rails method. You can get into a rails console by `rails c` and pass `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`. Then work around something like

```
t = Time.parse("2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530")
time_ago_in_words(t)
```

HTH

Comment: I tried at my console but it is giving error
irb(main):013:0> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object
irb(main):014:0> t = Time.parse(2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530)
SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
t = Time.parse(2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530)
                            ^
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

Answer (score 2):

Use This function

```
time_ago_in_words(from_time, include_seconds = false, options = {})
```

Refer Link : [ClickHere](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words)

```
irb> time = "2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530"
=> "2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530"
irb> helper.time_ago_in_words(time)
=> "about 3 hours"
```

OR another way :-
Include the ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper:

```
>> time_ago_in_words("2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530")
NoMethodError: undefined method `time_ago_in_words' for #<Object:0x3b0454>
from (irb):4
>> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object
>> time_ago_in_words("2013-04-19 11:07:37 +0530")
=> "about 3 hours"
```

Comment: I am doing this in IRB and it gives me an error `undefined method `time_ago_in_words'`

Comment: Please see the updated answer, in which you have to add helper before the time_ago_in_words. I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

time_ago_in_words and distance_of_time_in_words are Rails methods. You will have to define your own method to do this. Probably you could copy the code from rails.