# How to just show minutes or hours or weeks in rails time ago?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to get the following result based on created_at:

1-59M

1-24H

1-999+W

E.g, if a post is 5 minutes old it will say `5M`. If it is 15 hours old it will say: `15H` and lastly it will say `52W` if it is 52 weeks old.

Bonus: how would I make it work with: https://github.com/basecamp/local_time

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195740/how-do-you-do-relative-time-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want it in weeks, hours or minutes?  How about this (it would go in a helpers file)

```
def short_age_string(time)
  diff = Time.now - time #value is seconds (float)
  if diff >= 0
    result = "1-"
  else
    result = "1+"
  end
  diff = diff.abs.to_i
  if diff >= 604800 #seconds in a week
    weeks = diff/604800
    return "#{result}#{weeks}#{"+" if weeks >= 999}W"
  elsif diff > 3600 #seconds in an hour
    return "#{result}#{diff/3600}H"
  else
    return "#{diff/60}#{minutes}M"
  end
end
```

I took the liberty of making it return "1+..." for times in the future.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to get it to work with: https://github.com/basecamp/local_time ?

Comment: This gives you the "distance" between two times, so whatever time zone the user is in shouldn't make any difference.  Your database times will be in UTC which is what Time.now should return too.  Basically as long as `time` and `Time.now` are using the same timezone (which they should by default i believe: they are both just "seconds since epoch" under the hood - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing) then the maths will still work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd use [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to manage it with [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

According to [strftimer](http://strftimer.com/), you'd need to use `%-dH`, `%-dM`, `%-dD`, `%-dW` to get the format you desire:

```
#view
<%=l record.created_at, format: :small %>

#config/locales/en.yml
time:
   small: %-dH
```

I've tried testing this & it will only bring back the initial number. More testing is needed, but should set you on the right track

Comment: Doesn't this mean you'd need a conditional for each type? E.g, seconds, minute, days, weeks? How would that work with: https://github.com/basecamp/local_time ?